# Running a Node.js server in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Node.js web server which, as part of a CD process, I want to deploy to a staging server using Azure Release Pipeline. The problem is, that if I just run a Powershell script:

```
# Run-Server.ps1
node my-server.js
```

The Pipeline will hold since the node process blocks the Powershell session.
What I want is to be able to launch the service, and then in the next deployment just kill the node process and run it again with the new code.

So I figured I'll use `Start-Process`. If I run it locally:

```
> Start-Process node -ArgumentList ./server.js
```

I can now exit the Powershell session and the server will continue running. So I thought I can implement it the same way in my Release Pipeline.

But it turns out that once the Release Pipeline ends running, the server is no longer available - the node process is gone.

Can you help me figure out why is that? Is there another way of achieving this? I suppose it's a pretty common use case so there must be best-practices out there regarding to how this should be done.

Comment: Why would you want to run this app as apart of your pipeline?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej - I think it's a pretty common use case to deploy your application to a staging environment so you can test it, before you deploy it to production. The docs about Release Pipelines are filled with this.

Comment: Yes, but pipeline infrastracture is not your staging environment and as far I understood what you wrote you try to run it on the build agent.

Comment: I try to run it on a server configured in a Deployment Group

Comment: Ok. Got it. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, A pipeline job cleans up all of the child processes it spins up when it exits. This is killing your node server.

Set `Process.Clean` variable to `false` to override the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this is to use a full-blown web server to host andmanage node process. I.e. on Windows you could use [IIS with iisnode module](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html). This is more reliable and gives you a few other benefits:

- process management (automatic start, restart on failure, etc.)
- security - you can configure the user that node process will run as
- scalability on multi-core CPUs

Then the process of app deployment would be just copying files to the right directory - the web server should pick up the change automatically.